# Deactivate UAC in Windows 7 for a specific program

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-tasks, uac

I have a program that should run every night. Another is started every boot.

Both programms trigger the UAC-Window. At least with the nightly scheduled programm this is very bad, since my PC is waiting the whole night long for my confirmation of the UAC dialog. At the moment I am able to confirm it, that program causes much slowdown and I cancel it anyway.

So is there a way, that windows will start these 2 programms without prompting me everytime without deactivating UAC in general?

Comment: If it is a scheduled task, have it run as the `SYSTEM` user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the following article, it's applicable to Windows 7 as well:

[Selectively disable UAC for your trusted Vista applications](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/window-on-windows/selectively-disable-uac-for-your-trusted-vista-applications/635).