# How do you handle "File Access Denied" when deleting a file with the FileInfo.Delete method in VB

Tags: vb.net

I am  deleting log files >= 2 days old on a server with the following code:

```
        'Iterate through all files in specified path
        For Each file As IO.FileInfo In New IO.DirectoryInfo(sDirPath).GetFiles(sFileType)

            'Delete all log files 2 days old or older
            If (Now - file.CreationTime).Days >= iNumDays Then
                file.Delete()
            End If

        Next
```

This code works find on a regular windows machine.  On the server, it is setup to query the user for Administrative permissions and click continue to delete the file.  I have admin rights on the server.  My question is, how do you "click Continue" in code when the file.Delete method is executed?

Comment: Did you try to disable UAC?

Comment: No, because the server administrator wants to leave it on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope these are useful:

- [Create elevated Shortcut to run Program bypassing UAC Prompt in
  Windows 8 |
  7](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/create-elevated-shortcut-run-programs-bypass-uac)
- [Deactivate UAC in Windows 7 for a specific
  program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10453299/deactivate-uac-in-windows-7-for-a-specific-program)

Comment: It's a great workaround.  But I need to run this as an automated task each day.

Comment: Why don't you make it as 'Windows Service' and run it using`LocalSystem` account, this will solve you issue.

Comment: I ended up using scheduler and created the elevated shortcut as suggested.  It worked as advertised.